# Error while populating bootstrap treeview from data retrieved using Ajax call

Tags: ajax, treeview, bootstrap-treeview

I am using bootstrap treeview plugin (https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview). I am not sure if this is an issue with treeview plugin or the way i am implementing the code.I am trying to load the treeview using data from ajax call back. Here is the code sample that i am using:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  <!-- Required Javascript -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="~/Content/BootStrap/bootstrap-treeview.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="clear-fix"> </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"><div id="lstCollections">This will display my list of all collections</div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getTree(handleData) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '@Url.Action("Get","DatabaseSchema")',   
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (response) {
        handleData(response);
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    getTree(function (output) {
    var collectionTree = [];

      output.forEach(function (a) {
        collectionTree.push({ text: a });
      });

      //var tree2 = [{ text: "Buyer" }, {text: "text1" }, { text: "text2" }, { text: "text3" }];


      $('#lstCollections').treeview({ data: collectionTree });
    });
  })

</script>
```

When I run the code, I don't see any data in my treeview. In my developer tool(for chrome browser), in console I see "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treeview is not a function(…)" error on line " $('#lstCollections').treeview({ data: collectionTree });"

If i replace `$('#lstCollections').treeview({ data: collectionTree });`with `$('#lstCollections').treeview({ data: tree2});` (where tree2 is a variable that i have declared inside document.ready function, I still get the same error.

Interestingly, If i populate the treeview using following call outside of ajax call back function :

```
function nonAjax() {
    var tree = [{ text: "Buyer" }, { text: "text1" }, { text: "text2" }, { text: "text3" }];
    return tree;
}
$('#lstCollections').treeview({` data: nonAjax() });
```

Everything works!!
I am not sure why I am gettig treeview is not function() when the call is inside ajax callback function.

Comment: Damned good question. My treeview isn't working either. It's the fourth I've tried as documented.

Answer (score 0):

The right format that should pass to the treeview isn't what you get back from the Ajax call you should parse the json object like the following example:

```
let invalid = '{ "bank": "CityBank", "sum": "500" }, { "bank": "WPBank", "sum": "700" }';
let valid = JSON.parse("[" + invalid + "]");
```

Now you can pass the valid variable to the treeView without any problems.

It all about adding square brackets notation to the JSON object!